# How to connect two pandas data frames from right and left?

Tags: merge, append, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to do the following in a more elegant way (i.e. with fewer commands):

```
df_1 = pandas.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':[10,20,30]})
df_2 = pandas.DataFrame({'col3':[100,200,300], 'col4':[1000,2000,3000]})

for col in ['col3','col4']:
    df_1[col] = df_2[col]

print df_1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.tools.merge.concat.html)

```
In [407]: pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1)
Out[407]: 
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1    10   100  1000
1     2    20   200  2000
2     3    30   300  3000
```